# How can I open a file whose name starts with "-"?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, zsh

I am running Ubuntu, and would like to open a file whose file name starts with "-"(minus). When I try to open the file with pico or vim, the command thinks that the "-" sign is an option for the command.

I tried enclosing the file name with quotes ('), but I still get the same error.

I tried with bash and zsh, but still the same error.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In cases where `command -- -file` does not work - since not every program uses the same option parsing routines, `command ./-file` works everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

Place `--` just before file name. In Unix it indicates the end of options for command.

To be more concrete, use: `vim -- -file`.

Comment: Often, but not always, since it's left to the called command to interpret options however it prefers.  For example, compare `echo -n test` and `echo -- -n test`.  Check your manpages to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to open a file start with -
I'v tried many ways so that I started to search for it.
finally I've tried to type `cat ./-`
and it worked with me. thanks for your help Jastin